# Why my pycharm recommend me a deleted table on mysql?

Tags: python, mysql, database, pycharm

[image: enter image description here]]
[image]

As you see, Pycharm provide auto-completion for table name.

But in this case, it show me the deleted table 'uniq'.

Why? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The previous answer was not right. Yeah, sometimes PyCharm (or DataGrip, or any IntelliJ-based IDE, whatever: they are the same) doesn't understand if you deleted a table. But you **don't have** this table in the database tree. It means, that your database is synchronized up to date and this table is not supposed to be in code completion.

What happens then? You can see the source of the completion in pop-up — and here we have *db1@localhost [mySql Study 101-200]**.sql***

**.sql** means that it comes not from the database, but from the query console. I am nearly sure that you have *CREATE* script for this table upper in this script.

Comment: Alas, you are right ! Thank you very much ! I've never thought that case.